# Mapping roles in Jit Provisioning WSO2 IS

Tags: wso2, jit, federated-identity, wso2-identity-server

I'm using Google Federated Authenticator as IDP and i have problem with Jit provisioning. 
After successful login account is created in User Store witch i choose, but created user doesn't have role that i set in claim configuration.

Logs from Identity Server:

http://pastebin.com/7Rd7mrV2

How to configure IDP to set a role to accounts created with Jit?

Comment: What is the IS version you are using?
Also if possible post the relevant claim config section of the IDP as a screenshot

Comment: IS version 5.3.0 (KeyManager integrated with WSO2 AM) 
Here screenshots from IDP config : http://imgur.com/a/YNlvE.

Here screenshots from SP config : http://imgur.com/a/BvJqi

Comment: I use that configuration to generate token with scope that needs specific role. Token is generated after login by google but when i try to use this token to invoke api it fails in validation because user doesn't got mapped role.